is there any possibility of a view-change activity in ethereum 2?
As I understand ethereum 2 is based on proof of stake. In that sense, how is a leader or block proposer nominated in ethereum 2? Does the leader have to propose a block and drive the whole consensus by talking with other validators multiple rounds?
is there any possibility of a view-change activity in ethereum 2?

There is no such thing as "Ethereum 2". It is just Ethereum. What do you mean by "view-change"? This is not a term I'm aware of
